# Convergence/Divergence of $\sum \frac{n^2}{2^{nr}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Determine whether $\displaystyle \sum \frac{n^2}{2^{nr}}$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$,
>   diverges or converges

**Working:**

Consider the ratio test:
\begin{align*} 
\lim \left| \frac{(n+1)^2}{2^{(n+1)r}} \cdot \frac{2^{nr}}{n^2} \right| & =  \lim \left| \frac{(n^2+2n+1)2^{nr}}{2^{nr+r}n^2} \right| \\
& = \frac{1}{2^r} \lim \left(\frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2} \right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2^r} \lim \left( 1+\frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2^r} \cdot 1 \ \ \ \ \text{By the Algebraic Limit Theorem} \\
& = \frac{1}{2^r} 
\end{align*}
Note there are now three cases to consider:

- If $r=0$, then $\frac{1}{2^r} = 1$, hence no conclusion can be made.
- If $r>0$, then $0 < \frac{1}{2^r} < 1$, so $\sum \frac{n^2}{2^{nr}}$ is absolutely convergent.
- If $r<0$, then $\frac{1}{2^r} > 1$, so $\sum \frac{n^2}{2^{nr}}$
  diverges.

Now consider the case $r=0$ separately.

If $r=0$, then $\sum \frac{n^2}{2^{nr}} = \sum n^2$. Let $(b_n) = n^2$, then $(b_n) \rightarrow +\infty$. To prove this, we must show that for all $H >0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n \ge N$, then $b_n \ge H$. Let $H >0$ and pick a natural $N$ such that $N \ge \sqrt{H}$, then $n \ge N \ge \sqrt{H} \implies n^2 \ge H$, as required. Finally, using the [term test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test), since $(b_n) \not\rightarrow 0$, then $\sum n^2$ diverges. Thus, when $r=0$, the series $\sum \frac{n^2}{2^{nr}}$ diverges.

---

Question: Am I correct in splitting this question into three cases? Although the question itself didn't mention it, the divergence/convergence of this series clearly depends on what $r$ is, right?

Also is my proof for the case $r = 0$ correct? Specifically, when using the term test, an expression like $(b_n) \rightarrow +\infty$ can be considered as a specific case of $(b_n) \not\rightarrow 0$, right? Even though $+\infty$ isn't technically a number...

Comment: I think that you complicate a bit your answer by proving that $n^2\to\infty$ which's in my opinion not necessary since it's trivial and this is not the objective of the question.

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the convergence/divergence depends on $r$. In your case, the series converges when $\dfrac1{2^r} < 1$, i.e., for $r>0$. Specifically for $r=0$, note that the sum is $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2$, which clearly diverges.

---

For $r>0$, you can infact simplify and obtain a closed form as shown below.

First note that for $\vert x \vert < 1$, we have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \dfrac1{1-x}$. Differentiating once we get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} = \dfrac1{(1-x)^2}$$
Multiplying by $x$ and differentiating again, we get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2x^{n-1} = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2} \right) = \dfrac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2x^{n} = \dfrac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$$
Set $x=\dfrac1{2^r}$ to get the value of the series.